# Correct algorithms with sequentially inconsistent executions

Tags: concurrency

as far as I understood one wants that an algorithm produces only results that can be also achieved by a sequentially consistent execution.

My question is whether this is true or whether there are correct algorithms that have results that can be only achieved by sequentially inconsistent executions?

Comment: This comment is only _loosely_ related to your problem. In the field of _distributed shared memory_, there are various read/write objects with different consistency conditions. The solutions to mutual exclusion problem are different when you use different read/write objects. However, I think the solution with *weak* objects is still correct when you replace them with *strong* ones. The reverse is not necessarily right.